# 'Thanks for submitting an edit' banner is missing a period

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, wording

When you submit a suggested edit, the following notice is shown:

> **Thanks for submitting an edit.** It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members

(the word 'approved' links to the suggested edit itself)

I can't help but notice the last sentence is missing a period at the end. Other similar notices (for closed questions or for migrated questions) do have one

Comment: I see what you did there :)

Comment: This was now raised also on [math.meta.se]: [Should it be "trusted community members" or "trusted community members."?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34401) (And marked ([tag:status-review]) by one of the local mods.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Martin noticed, this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed):

[image]