# Some banners still have the yellow colour scheme. Can it be changed to blue like the rest of the post notices?

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, suggested-edits, post-notices

When I suggested an edit to a question here on MSE, I noticed that the banner saying "Thanks for submitting an edit" is yellow in colour, which was the colour scheme before the [new post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/313042) were rolled out. I think all the notices are now uniformly in blue, so this banner is the only exception.

> [image: "Thanks for submitting an edit" banner]

Can this banner also be changed to blue like the rest of the post notices? (And while we're at it, can we [add a full stop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345404/313042) at the end, as well?)

---

Edit: I'm pulling up @Catija♦'s comments below for greater visibility:

> Brahadeesh, I’m pretty sure the difference is between new and old. I think we just haven’t updated the yellow ones to the new code styling. <sup>[[Source]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347635/some-banners-still-have-the-yellow-colour-scheme-can-it-be-changed-to-blue-like#comment1164405_347635)</sup>
>
> There's still lots of the site that have to be brought into our "[stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/)" format... we're making changes gradually but it's going to take a while. The sites are pretty complex. <sup>[[Source]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347635/some-banners-still-have-the-yellow-colour-scheme-can-it-be-changed-to-blue-like#comment1164408_347635)</sup>

I also noticed a few other places where yellow banners are used instead of blue ones.

After I had a flag declined on Music Fans Meta, I got a banner saying "Your recent flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!" the next time I tried flagging a post:

> [image: "Your recent flag was declined" banner]

When I tried editing a tag's info on Music Fans, I got a banner saying "You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges":

> [image: "tag wiki edit privileges" banner]

Comment: Can you get moderators to notice this?

Comment: @CulverKwan I suppose that one can flag this question for moderator attention requesting them to escalate it higher as per the [new guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345032/313042), but I've never done this on Meta SE. Since this question has been up for very little time, I'm also wondering whether doing so might be a bit premature. In short, I don't know. . . But, I also suspect that the SE developers keep an eye on the questions tagged [tag:bug] and attend to those they consider urgent.

Comment: @Brahadeesh it changed, these days the proper course of action is to ask a moderator to add a [tag:status-review] to the question, then the developers take from the pool of questions with that tag. Otherwise, without the review tag, there's a very small chance that SE staff/developers will take a look on the request.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance Thank you for explaining that to me, I shall flag this post for moderator attention now.

Comment: I wonder if its by design. The featured post block on the is yellow too

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Gosh, how did I miss that! Hmm. . . Leaving the Featured tab aside since it's not a long horizontal rectangular banner, the Suggested Edit and Flag Warning banners were jarring in their colours to me, since I was so used to seeing them blue. Maybe I should remove the [bug] tag?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8qfo.png kinda makes it so much more obvious, when they're next to each other :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek XD That's. . .I have nothing to say *hides in a corner*

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance considering that more status review tags were added by staff than mods, that argument doesn’t really work. Brahadeesh, I’m pretty sure the difference is between new and old. I think we just haven’t updated the yellow ones to the new code styling.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for letting us know, I presume that there are plans for updating all of the yellow ones, then? :)

Comment: There's still lots of the site that have to be brought into our "[stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/)" format... we're making changes gradually but it's going to take a while. The sites are pretty complex.

Comment: The suggested edit notices used to be block quotes (>) and have been replaced with proper notices (Stacks component) simultaneously with the other changes. Hence I'd assume that the color is intentional. /cc @Catija

Comment: @Catija wasn't it before the announcement? I didn't check exact numbers since then, but did see quite a few such tags added by mods.

Answer (score 5):

While I don't have an *inside* view of the issue (and staff are welcome to point out if I'm wrong) - to my eye, it's pretty obvious that the different colour is for things that need to be noticed. [image]

Side by side from the question - it's pretty clear those post notices, much like the featured on meta block are meant to grab the attention of the viewer, and follow the same theme