# Date selection text highlight isn't inline on the The Overflow blog

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, the-overflow

The text selection highlight for dates in [*The Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.blog/) blog is sometimes not entirely inline with the date. Selecting the date adds a small highlight to the left that's offset.

I noticed this because I often select the date to read it better. It happens on the main page and on the detailed articles but not with the dates of the *"Most popular"* or the *"The Stack Overflow Podcast"* sections.

[image: screenshot of text highlight of date in The Overflow blog]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that constitutes a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).
Furthermore, it's not actually the date, it's a `whitespace` between the tag and topic divs that gets selected as well:

[image]

That `whitespace` could simply be removed, and the problem would be gone.

Comment: Maybe I should tag the question as feature-request instead of bug? I don't know but it isn't pleasing visually and the div should somehow not be selectable or be removed. I am inclined to accept your answer since it pinpoints the cause of the issue...

Comment: I think that would be more appropriate, but since it hasn't been brought up yet I'm not sure if it matters a lot (e.g. [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345404/thanks-for-submitting-an-edit-banner-is-missing-a-period) is also tagged with [tag:bug]). I do agree it doesn't look right, and it seems like a small fix to make.